# Phonegap Relational Database

Tags: android, iphone, database, sqlite, cordova

I'm creating a Phonegap / Cordova application which is going to pull a lot of list views from a relational database.

When I search around, a lot of the stuff I find on the web is around HTML5 localstorage and the client-side database within iPhone which has a limit of 5mb.

I expect my database to be larger than 5mb so I want to try and bundle SQLite with my Application... or at least I think I want to!

What is the best approach for a relational database on Phonegap (iphone / android)? How do you bundle a database with a PhoneGap app?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9161567/1321873

Answer (score 1):

You may look a jembe for this (http://www.jembe.fr). jembe let you embed a [big sqlite database](http://blog.jembe.fr/creer-un-projet-avec-une-base-de-donnees-prepopulate/). The API to access this database is similar to standard js API.

Comment: Looks interesting but unfortunately my French is not good enough to understand the site / examples... they don't seem to have an english language version. It looks like a Phonegap substitute as well...

Comment: It does what phonegap do. But phonegap is based on the webkit database only. On Jembe, you can also use the webkit database if your database is less than 5M. Also, I'm not sure that you can package your application with a prepopulated database with phonegap. Hope that they will make an english version soon